# Get the positions of unique elements in a string[]

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, label

I have an xml file that I am accessing to create a report of time spent on a project. I'm returning the unique dates to a label created dynamically on a winform and would like to compile the time spent on a project for each unique date. I have been able to return all of the projects under each date or only one project. Currently I'm stuck on only returning one project. Can anyone please help me?? This is what the data should look like if it's correct.

```
04/11/15
    26820   2.25
    27111   8.00
04/12/15
    26820   8.00
04/13/15
    01det   4.33
    26820   1.33
    27225   4.25

etc.
```

This is how I'm retrieving the data

```
         string[] weekDateString = elementDateWeekstring();
         string[] uniqueDates = null;
         string[] weeklyJobNumber = elementJobNumWeek();
         string[] weeklyTicks = elementTicksWeek();
```

This is how I'm getting the unique dates.

```
         IEnumerable<string> distinctWeekDateIE = weekDateString.Distinct();

         foreach (string d in distinctWeekDateIE)
         {
             uniqueDates = distinctWeekDateIE.ToArray();
         }
```

And this is how I'm creating the labels.

```
        try
         {
              int dateCount;
              dateCount = uniqueDates.Length;

              Label[] lblDate = new Label[dateCount];
              int htDate = 1;
              int padDate = 10;

              for (int i = 0; i < dateCount; i++ )
              {
                   lblDate[i] = new Label();

                   lblDate[i].Name = uniqueDates[i].Trim('\r');

                   lblDate[i].Text = uniqueDates[i];

                   lblDate[i].TabIndex = i;

                   lblDate[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(18, 275 + padDate + htDate, 75, 22);

                   targetForm.Controls.Add(lblDate[i]);

                   htDate += 22;

                   foreach (string x in uniqueDates)
                   {
                        int[] posJobNumber;

                       posJobNumber = weekDateString.Select((b, a) => b == uniqueDates[i].ToString() ? a : -1).Where(a => a != -1).ToArray();

                        for (int pjn = 0; pjn < posJobNumber.Length; pjn++)
                        {

                             if (x.Equals(lblDate[i].Text))
                             {

                                  Label lblJobNum = new Label();

                                  int htJobNum = 1;
                                  int padJobNum = 10;

                                  lblJobNum.Name = weeklyJobNumber[i];

                                  lblJobNum.Text = weeklyJobNumber[i];

                                  lblJobNum.Bounds = new Rectangle(100, 295 + padJobNum + htJobNum, 75, 22);

                                  targetForm.Controls.Add(lblJobNum);

                                  htJobNum += 22;
                                  htDate += 22;
                                  padJobNum += 22;
                             }
                        }

                     }
              }
         }
```

I've been stuck on this for about 3 months. Is there anyone that can describe to me why I'm not able to properly retrieve the job numbers that are associated with a particular date. I don't believe that these are specifically being returned as dates. Just a string that looks like a date.

I really appreciate any help I can get. I'm just completely baffled. Thank you for any responses in advance. I truly appreciate the assistance.

EDIT: @Sayka - Here is the xml sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Form1>
  <Name Key="4/21/2014 6:51:17 AM">
    <Date>4/21/2014</Date>
    <JobNum>26820</JobNum>
    <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
    <Task>Modeling Secondary</Task>
    <Start>06:51 AM</Start>
    <End>04:27 PM</End>
    <TotalTime>345945089017</TotalTime>
  </Name>
  <Name Key="4/22/2014 5:44:22 AM">
    <Date>4/22/2014</Date>
    <JobNum>26820</JobNum>
    <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
    <Task>Modeling Secondary</Task>
    <Start>05:44 AM</Start>
    <End>06:56 AM</End>
    <TotalTime>43514201221</TotalTime>
  </Name>
  <Name Key="4/22/2014 6:57:02 AM">
    <Date>4/22/2014</Date>
    <JobNum>02e-n-g</JobNum>
    <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
    <Task>NET Eng</Task>
    <Start>06:57 AM</Start>
    <End>07:16 AM</End>
    <TotalTime>11706118875</TotalTime>
  </Name>
....
</Form1>
```

This is how I'm getting the information out of the xml file and returning a string[].

```
    public static string[] elementDateWeekstring()
    {
        //string datetxtWeek = "";
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

        fileExistsWeek(xmldoc);

        XmlNodeList nodeDate = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Date");

        int countTicks = 0;
        string[] dateTxtWeek = new string[nodeDate.Count];


        for (int i = 0; i < nodeDate.Count; i++)
        {
            dateTxtWeek[i] = nodeDate[i].InnerText;
            countTicks++;

        }
        return dateTxtWeek;
    }
```

Job number and Ticks are returned in a similar fashion. I've been able to reuse these snippets throught out the code. This is a one dimensional xml file?? It will always return a position for a jobnumber that equates to a date or Ticks. I will never have more or less of any one element.

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Breakpoints? Single step through your code? Compared expected values to actual values? Where is the first mismatch? What is the first thing which goes wrong? Where exactly does it happen? Why?

Comment: In the 'foreach()' at the posJobNumber = .... It returns the first job number that matches the first date, and then it just keeps looping through. It's like it's not incrementing in that statement. I don't understand (I think) this LINQ statement?? I think that's what it's called. I originally tried to return .IndexOf but I was unable to return just those that match a date successfully.

Comment: How comes you use a LINQ statement you don't understand? Code it as an explicit loop and see if this works better.

Comment: Well that sounds like what I have to do. I'll go back to the IndexOf. I think it wants to pull in all of the elements, not just matching ones. Thank you for your advice @DrKoch. I appreciate it :-D

Comment: how can you put the name of the Label, a number?

Comment: will guv you a good solution if you provide some Input/Output samples. If you're taking input from xml file means provide it along with the question

Comment: @Sayka That's gonna take a minute. I'll definitely put it up shortly. The name of the label as a number I think I was at one point deciding to add the index of the item as part of the label name, not the displayed text, so that I could go back and get the positions of the Ticks more easily. I'm not sure if that will work or not. I know I need to get those unique job numbers in relation to the dates first.

Comment: can you explain htJobNum += 22;

Comment: That increments the location of the '.Bounds' of the Label. The next one will be placed 22 pixels below the previous one.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's hard if not impossible to know for sure how best to fix your code. That said, given the problem description it seems that what you ought to be doing is using LINQ's `GroupBy()` method to group your data by date, then `OrderBy()` to sort it, and then finally enumerating the resulting groups with their elements to populate the labels. By keeping your data in an object type that preserves the full data you want to display, not just the date, it's a simple matter to convert the fields to labels as needed

Comment: The main thing you need to explain is What you mean by 26820   2.25 below date  4/11/2015; And also by taking unique dates, do you want to sum up the time? Is 2.25 the difference of start and end time? Hours: What to do with the 3 nodes of same dates?

Comment: @Sayka 26820 is a job project number and the 2.25 would be the total amount of time spent on that project. I may have been in that project for 1 hour on the 11th of april in the morning and then worked on another job for most of the rest of the day until I get some information. Then I spend 1.25 hours finishing up the project. Unique dates I may have 100 entries with the date 4/11/2015 and I may have 1. If there are 100 entries with that date I need to get the job numbers that I worked on for that date. May be 2 and may be 100 of them. I already (hopefully) have a snippet to add the Ticks()

Comment: I've made a good one. But i think adding labels will be fine for small data. But if the data grows up, it would be a problem. May i giv u a nice solution with a datagridview with blank grid color that gives u something as you've shown above?

Comment: @Sayka at some point it actually will grow. The idea for this one is for the user to be able to summarize his/her work at the end of everyweek. At some point, once I've tackled this one, I want to be able to have a supervisor to load another file xml file I'm generating by selecting a userID and it will create some charting. I'd love to see your data grid. I think I stepped back from this at one point as it had limitations with charting. As I am a very new NEWB, I could be very wrong in the way I've been reading the dataGrid research I've done. I'd love to see it!! Thank You!! :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq-to-XML to parse the XML file, and then use Linq-to-objects to group (and order) the data by job date and order each group by job name.

The code to parse the XML file is like so:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var jobs = doc.Descendants("Name");

// Extract the date, job number, and total time from each "Name" element.:

var data = jobs.Select(job => new
{
    Date = (DateTime)job.Element("Date"),
    Number = (string)job.Element("JobNum"),
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)job.Element("TotalTime"))
});
```

The code to group and order the jobs by date and order the groups by job name is:

```
var result = 
    data.GroupBy(job => job.Date).OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Date = g.Key, 
        Jobs = g.OrderBy(item => item.Number)
    });
```

Then you can access the data by iterating over each group in `result` and then iterate over each job in the group, like so:

```
foreach (var jobsOnDate in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:d}", jobsOnDate.Date);

    foreach (var job in jobsOnDate.Jobs)
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}  {1:hh\\:mm}", job.Number, job.Duration);
}
```

Putting this all together in a sample compilable console application (substitute the filename for the XML file as appropriate):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            string filename = @"d:\test\test.xml"; // Substitute your own filename here.

            // Open XML file and get a collection of each "Name" element.            

            var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            var jobs = doc.Descendants("Name");

            // Extract the date, job number, and total time from each "Name" element.:

            var data = jobs.Select(job => new
            {
                Date = (DateTime)job.Element("Date"),
                Number = (string)job.Element("JobNum"),
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)job.Element("TotalTime"))
            });

            // Group the jobs by date, and order the groups by job name:

            var result = 
                data.GroupBy(job => job.Date).OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    Date = g.Key, 
                    Jobs = g.OrderBy(item => item.Number)
                });

            // Print out the results:

            foreach (var jobsOnDate in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0:d}", jobsOnDate.Date);

                foreach (var job in jobsOnDate.Jobs)
                    Console.WriteLine("    {0}  {1:hh\\:mm}", job.Number, job.Duration);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Frank The best approach might be to single-step through it in the debugger, and try it with different sets of data in the XML file to check that the output is what you want.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'm just getting back into this. Code is not my real job. I'm looking at this and trying to understand. I'm ordering things, using your code, but not creating the labels. Is that correct?? My label code will go where the 'Console.WriteLine()' is

Answer (score 0):

The output is like this

[image]

Create a new project

Set form size bigger.

Apply these codes.

Set the location for your XML file.

**Namespaces**

```
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
```

**Form Code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const string XML_FILE_NAME = "D:\\emps.txt";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        prepareDataGrid();
        List<JOBS> jobsList = prepareXML(XML_FILE_NAME);
        for (int i = 0; i < jobsList.Count; i++)
        {
            addDateRow(jobsList[i].jobDate.ToString("M'/'d'/'yyyy"));
            for (int j = 0; j < jobsList[i].jobDetailsList.Count; j++)
                dgv.Rows.Add(new string[] { 
                    jobsList[i].jobDetailsList[j].JobNumber,
                    jobsList[i].jobDetailsList[j].JobHours
                });
        }
    }

    DataGridView dgv;
    void prepareDataGrid()
    {
        dgv = new DataGridView();
        dgv.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        dgv.GridColor = Color.White;
        dgv.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
        dgv.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black;
        dgv.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        dgv.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        dgv.Width = 600;
        dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        dgv.Columns.Add("Col1", "Col1");
        dgv.Columns.Add("Col2", "Col2");
        dgv.Columns[0].Width = 110;
        dgv.Columns[1].Width = 40;
        dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10);
        dgv.RowHeadersVisible = dgv.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows =
        dgv.AllowUserToDeleteRows =
        dgv.AllowUserToOrderColumns =
        dgv.AllowUserToResizeColumns =
        dgv.AllowUserToResizeRows =
        !(dgv.ReadOnly = true);
        Controls.Add(dgv);
    }

    void addJobRow(string jobNum, string jobHours)
    {
        dgv.Rows.Add(new string[] {jobNum, jobHours });
    }

    void addDateRow(string date)
    {
        dgv.Rows.Add(new string[] { date, ""});
        dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor =
        dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Firebrick;
        dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Segoe UI Light", 13.5F);
        dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Height = 25;
    }

    List<JOBS> prepareXML(string fileName)
    {
        string xmlContent = "";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs)) xmlContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlContent);

        List<JOBS> jobsList = new List<JOBS>();
        XmlNode form1Node = doc.ChildNodes[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < form1Node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlNode dateNode = form1Node.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0],
                jobNumNode = form1Node.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0],
                timeTicksNode = form1Node.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[6].ChildNodes[0];

            bool foundDate = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < jobsList.Count; j++) if (jobsList[j].compareDate(dateNode.Value))
                {
                    jobsList[j].addJob(jobNumNode.Value, Math.Round(TimeSpan.FromTicks(
                        (long)Convert.ToDouble(timeTicksNode.Value)).TotalHours, 2).ToString());
                    foundDate = true;
                    break;
                }
            if (!foundDate)
            {
                JOBS job = new JOBS(dateNode.Value);
                string jbnum = jobNumNode.Value;
                string tbtck = timeTicksNode.Value;
                long tktk = Convert.ToInt64(tbtck);
                double tkdb = TimeSpan.FromTicks(tktk).TotalHours;
                job.addJob(jobNumNode.Value, Math.Round(TimeSpan.FromTicks(
                        Convert.ToInt64(timeTicksNode.Value)).TotalHours, 2).ToString());
                jobsList.Add(job);
            }
        }
        jobsList.OrderByDescending(x => x.jobDate);
        return jobsList;
    }

    class JOBS
    {
        public DateTime jobDate;
        public List<JobDetails> jobDetailsList = new List<JobDetails>();

        public void addJob(string jobNumber, string jobHours)
        {
            jobDetailsList.Add(new JobDetails() { JobHours = jobHours, JobNumber = jobNumber });
        }
        public JOBS(string dateString)
        {
            jobDate = getDateFromString(dateString);
        }

        public JOBS() { }

        public bool compareDate(string dateString)
        {
            return getDateFromString(dateString) == jobDate;
        }

        private DateTime getDateFromString(string dateString)
        {
            string[] vals = dateString.Split('/');
            return new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(vals[2]), Convert.ToInt32(vals[0]), Convert.ToInt32(vals[1]));
        }
    }

    class JobDetails
    {
        public string JobNumber { get; set; }
        public string JobHours { get; set; }
    }
}
```