# Trying to calculate xml values from DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I have successfully created a DataGridView based on the MS walkthrough for reading xml into a DataGridView.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekw4dh3f.aspx

I'm now trying to sort the information based on the date of the xml entry to calculate the total ticks present in the xml file. XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Form1>
  <Name Key="4/13/2015 6:31:26 AM">
    <Date>4/13/2015</Date>
    <JobNum>00000</JobNum>
    <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
    <Task>TimeStar</Task>
    <Start>06:31 AM</Start>
    <End>06:35 AM</End>
    <TotalTime>2163346393</TotalTime>
  </Name>
  <Name Key="4/13/2015 6:35:11 AM">
    <Date>4/13/2015</Date>
    <JobNum>27163</JobNum>
    <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
    <Task>Redlines</Task>
    <Start>06:35 AM</Start>
    <End>07:35 AM</End>
    <TotalTime>36229156954</TotalTime>
  </Name>
  //etc.
</Form1>
```

Basically I'm stuck at trying to gather all  of the `<Date>` fields/Rows only and then calculating the `<TotalTime>` for those rows. I tried doing this from the XML to dynamically create a label based on the unique date fields and then calculate any TotalTime fields that we're in that row.

[Get the positions of unique elements in a string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075817/get-the-positions-of-unique-elements-in-a-string)

I was told that it's easier with the DataGridView, but I believe that is not the case. Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to sort or filter either this or the previous question. I'm not getting it. I truly don't want the answer written for me. I'm just not able to wrap my head around it.

It seems to me the structure should be something like:

```
foreach(filter date)
{
    uniqueDate = true;
    new Label == CreateLabel();

    foreach(date = array[x])
    {
        if (date = array[x])
           {
               sum = TotalTime[x];
           }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with the structure of this please. Seems like the code should work for either the DataGridView or reading the XML directly.

Thank you very much in advance for any assistance you can help me with. I REALLY appreciate it :-)

**EDIT: This is where I'm getting the XMLException was unhandled - Data at the root level is invalid. Code is modified from Cedric's answer.**

```
public string sum2()
    {
        var document = XDocument.Parse(filePath);

        double getit = 0;

        foreach (var dates in document.Root.Elements("Name").GroupBy(i => i.Element("Date").Value))
        {
            double summ = 0;
            foreach (var date in dates)
            {
                summ += Convert.ToDouble(date.Element("TotalTime").Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Date {0} = {1}", dates.Key, summ);

            getit = summ;
        }

        double retunthis = getit;

        return retunthis.ToString();


    }
```

I'm calling this on the button click with `sum2();` Hoping to just see it in action in the console first. Not currently using any of the returned code.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are trying to sort the grid by the "TotalTime" column, so that you can calculate a sum of the "TotalTime" column?

Comment: No. Let me check the question. It's sorting by the <Date> to get all of the unique[x] dates. Then finding each row number of the unique[x] dates. In my other question I tried creating a new array but failed miserably.

Comment: In your code near the end of your question there is a little misuse of operators. "=" is an assignment operator used for assigning a value whereas, "==" is a comparative operator used to test two values or references for equality. You should change `new Label == CreateLabel();` to Label tempLabel = CreateLabel()` (Assuming you are using CreateLabel as a method that returns a Label object) then changing `foreach(date = array[x]) { if (date = array[x]) ...` to foreach (date in "whatever collection") { if (date == array[x]) { "do work" } ...`

Comment: I dont understand your question you want a sum of all total time for each day ?

Comment: @BerndLinde the xml block was not surrounded by the `code` instruction. Sorry. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @CalebB The code near the end is pure gibberish. I'm just trying to understand the structure. Is that the correct structure to loop through, find, create, then loop through again to find the locations, then add 5 to my index, retrieve and calculate??

Comment: @Cedric I want a sum of all time for each entry on just that date. I may have 45 entries of 30 minutes each on 4/14/15 and I may have one entry of 10 hours on 4/15/15.

Comment: Where would this dynamic label reside?

Comment: @Frank by your own words the code block is pure gibberish, so no.

Comment: @BerndLinde I actually have it in a Logic.cs file. I call it from there. Right now I'm sure what I'm asking is Sort or Filter and that's what folks are trying to provide me, but I'm sure I'm asking the wrong question. All of the searching I've done on Sort and Filter is using the function on the datagrid view to allow the user to do it. I want to do it dynamically. when they open the form the last 7 days (max) will just show up with a label and the total amount of time spent on each project. It's just a small time tracker application.

Comment: @CalebB Forgive me if it sounds like I was not truly replying to you. I was not making fun of what you noted. Like I said I'm just trying to get the structure right. Please forgive me if I have offended you. Thank you for commenting!! :-D I'm a newb. You understand how we are right?? :)

Comment: OK, I have an understanding of what you are trying to achiev, give me a bit to writeup something that you can you (Cedric method will work, I have a different approach)

Comment: @BerndLinde BONUS!! :-D

Comment: Nope, my idea is getting too complex :D

Comment: @Frank My answer worked ?

Comment: @Cedric Please forgive me. I'm going to do this today. I don't do this for a living. My real job is construction. I'm doing this as a side project. Right now we're slamming drawings into the shop. I will do it today. I promise!! :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is good.

Here is what I have :

```
var xml = "<Form1><Name Key='4/13/2015 6:31:26 AM'><Date>4/13/2015</Date><JobNum>00000</JobNum><RevNum>00000</RevNum><Task>TimeStar</Task><Start>06:31 AM</Start><End>06:35 AM</End><TotalTime>2163346393</TotalTime></Name><Name Key='4/13/2015 6:35:11 AM'><Date>4/13/2015</Date><JobNum>27163</JobNum><RevNum>00000</RevNum><Task>Redlines</Task><Start>06:35 AM</Start><End>07:35 AM</End><TotalTime>36229156954</TotalTime></Name><Name Key='4/13/2015 6:35:11 AM'><Date>6/13/2015</Date><JobNum>27163</JobNum><RevNum>00000</RevNum><Task>Redlines</Task><Start>06:35 AM</Start><End>07:35 AM</End><TotalTime>36229156954</TotalTime></Name></Form1>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (var dates in document.Root.Elements("Name").GroupBy(i => i.Element("Date").Value))
{
    double summ = 0;
    foreach (var date in dates)
    {
        summ += Convert.ToDouble(date.Element("TotalTime").Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine ("Date {0} = {1}", dates.Key, summ);
}
```

The output:

```
Date 4/13/2015 = 38392503347
Date 6/13/2015 = 36229156954
```

**Note that I added the date `6/13/2015` to your xml to have 2 different date**

XML:

```
<Form1>
  <Name Key="4/13/2015 6:31:26 AM">
    <Date>4/13/2015</Date>
    <JobNum>00000</JobNum>
    <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
    <Task>TimeStar</Task>
    <Start>06:31 AM</Start>
    <End>06:35 AM</End>
    <TotalTime>2163346393</TotalTime>
  </Name>
  <Name Key="4/13/2015 6:35:11 AM">
    <Date>4/13/2015</Date>
    <JobNum>27163</JobNum>
    <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
    <Task>Redlines</Task>
    <Start>06:35 AM</Start>
    <End>07:35 AM</End>
    <TotalTime>36229156954</TotalTime>
  </Name>
  <Name Key="6/13/2015 6:35:11 AM">
    <Date>6/13/2015</Date>
    <JobNum>27163</JobNum>
    <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
    <Task>Redlines</Task>
    <Start>06:35 AM</Start>
    <End>07:35 AM</End>
    <TotalTime>36229156954</TotalTime>
  </Name>
</Form1>
```

Comment: Cedric. That looks close. Let me plug that in and see what happens :-D Thank You!!

Comment: I'm still at this Cedric. Please see Edited code. I'm getting the error: XMLException unhandled. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, Position 1. I think I'm not declaring a new XDocument. :-(

Comment: If you're using a file path Use `XDocument.Load(FilePath);`

Comment: And your code wont work 

Only the last date will be return as a string

Comment: Ok. I remember this. I need to look at this. I have potentially blank or null values. I think that I need to make sure the values have all zeros if there is no value reported. A user can create an entry but it puts a null or blank "" entry and the code can't read it. I'm doing this in the testing by adding if statements. I think I need to tackle this now. You are the man!! (Woman??):-D Thanks Cedric!! Thank You very much